# How to maximise a window horizontal or vertically?

Tags: awesome

In [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/), what key binding can you use to maximise a window (in floating mode, of course) so that it maximise in just the horizontal or just the vertical direction?

I know that `mod4 + m` will maximise it fully in both directions so I kind of assume it will be possible to do a mapping to just one direction.

```
awesome v3.5.1 (Ruby Tuesday)
• Build: May 28 2013 18:46:22 for x86_64 by gcc version 4.8.0 (mockbuild@buildvm-23.phx2.fedoraproject.org)
• Compiled against Lua 5.1.4 (running with Lua 5.1)
• D-Bus support: ✔
```

But that is an ancient version! Yes, but this is on CentOS 7 where [compiling newer versions of Awesome is a PITA](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152258/10526). This one works for me just as it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default there is no such key binding (in `3.5.1`, see [other answer for `4.1`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/366757/115933)). But you can create one. Use this snippet (or better add the key binding to your existing configuration) for your `rc.lua` file:

```
clientkeys = awful.util.table.join(
  awful.key({ modkey }, "F7",
    function(c) c.maximized_horizontal = not c.maximized_horizontal end),
  awful.key({ modkey }, "F8",
    function(c) c.maximized_vertical   = not c.maximized_vertical end),
)
```

It assigns horizontal and vertical maximization to `mod-F7` and `mod-F8`, respectively.

Comment: Super. It all worked but I had to remove the comma at the end of the last but one line.

Answer (score 3):

Since awesome version 4.1 this is <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (vertical) and <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (horizontal) per default.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with the version number. I would leave the answer (maybe saying that for newer version) as it *is* a useful one to know.