# trying to install curl with homebrew, getting "incompatible library version" for libcurl.4.dylib

Tags: path, curl, homebrew

I am on OSX 10.9.5. I would like to use a later version of CURL than what is bundled with OSX, but I do not want to remove the OSX binary just in case, so I wanted to opt to install it via homebrew.

my PATH:

```
$ echo $PATH
/Users/Tom/.nvm/v0.10.33/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/Tom/.composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin::~/Library/Trigger\ Toolkit:/usr/local/heroku/bin
```

as you can see, `/usr/local/bin` is almost at the front of the `path`, behind my Node `nvm` path.

result of `$ brew install curl`:

```
Warning: curl-7.38.0 already installed
```

result of `$ curl`:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
[1]    6481 trace trap  curl
```

What did I do wrong with the installation? Why didn't brew include the required libcurl version?

Comment: Please read my answer in [Using Awesome window manager on CentOS 7](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152258/using-awesome-window-manager-on-centos-7)and my answer in [What is the correct way to resolve this rpm conflict? (Error: p11-kit-trust conflicts with nss-3.13.3-6.el6.x86_64)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167554/what-is-the-correct-way-to-resolve-this-rpm-conflict-error-p11-kit-trust-conf) and follow DisplayName's answer.  In order to update curl, you need to update OSX.  If OSX doesn't update curl you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

One solution was provided [here](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-10/0072.html)

The idea is to make a static build of curl and then paste it to you /usr/bin/ or /usr/local/bin/. Briefly:

1. `~$ xcode-select --install`
2. Download the latest version of [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).
3. cd to the directory and run

   `~$ ./configure --disable-shared --with-darwinssl --enable-threaded-resolver`

   ~$ make -j `sysctl -n hw.logicalcpu_max`
4. Copy the compiled curl, which is located in ./src/curl to you /usr/bin/

**Note:** In the make command in 3, the sign "`" is indeed back quote, not single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rm /usr/local/Cellar/curl` then reinstalling. (This will delete your homebrew curl.)

Homebrew says this when i test installed curl:

> Mac OS X already provides this software and installing another version in
>   parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.
>
> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
>   build variables:

```
LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib
CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/curl/include
```

Comment: I also get that same message from Homebrew. What does this mean I need to do? I Just want to be able to use a more recent version of curl when I type `curl` in terminal.

Comment: `export LIBCURL_CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include` and
`export LIBCURL_LIBS=-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib`

Comment: I added both those to my `.zshrc` and sourced it, but when I do `type curl` I'm still being pointed to the OSX bundled curl, not my brew version.