# OSX curl error with unprivileged user dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: osx, curl

My MAC OS is Yosemite 10.10, which has an old version of curl.  I have installed Xcode and Xcode command line tools.

```
I run cURL with the "sudo" command as  “sudo curl”:
    sudo curl
    Password:
    curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information

However, when I run curl under the common user in the the terminal, it failed as follows:

  dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 5.0.0
  Trace/BPT trap: 5


  I also downloaded the curl version of 7.43, and installed in /usr/local/bin.

  —  "which curl”  shows “/usr/local/bin/curl” 
  —  otool shows:
     otool -L /usr/local/bin/curl
     /usr/local/bin/curl:
     /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
     /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
     /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
     /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
     /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
      /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)

   otool -L /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib 
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib:
    /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.8, current version 0.9.8)
     /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2.4.0)
     /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

However, the curl still work with "sudo" but failed for common user, i.e.,

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 5.0.0
  Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Meanwhile, the previous solution ([trying to install curl with homebrew, getting "incompatible library version" for libcurl.4.dylib](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164637/trying-to-install-curl-with-homebrew-getting-incompatible-library-version-for)) did not work for my case.

-- More ----

Actually, the commands which seems to call the libcurl failed to run with the same information, e.g.:

--MacPorts:

```
  [user @MBK ~]$port

  dlopen(/opt/local/libexec/macports/lib/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib, 6): Library not   loaded: /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
   Referenced from: /opt/local/libexec/macports/lib/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib
   Reason: Incompatible library version: Pextlib.dylib requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 5.0.0
    while executing "load /opt/local/libexec/macports/lib/pextlib1.0/Pextlib.dylib"
    ("package ifneeded Pextlib 1.0" script)
    invoked from within "package require Pextlib 1.0"
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 47)
```

-- Netcdf :

```
 [user@MBK ~]$ncdump 

  dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
   Referenced from: /opt/local/bin/ncdump
   Reason: Incompatible library version: ncdump requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 5.0.0
  Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Again, the commands with "sudo" work.

Comment: The output of `type curl` while you are using the user would be good to have. Also not sure if OSX includes `ldd` but give it a try using `ldd /path/to/curl` where the path is the result of `type` before.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!  type curl shows that "curl is hashed (/usr/local/bin/curl)", however, ldd can not be found in OSX.

Comment: What are the permissions of `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib` & `/usr/local/lib` & `/usr/local` ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, running

```
curl http://some.site
```

gave

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/samh/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib
Reason: image not found
```

however, running `conda install libssh2` fixed the problem. This makes no sense to me, since curl has worked on my machine for years... but at least it works now.

Comment: Thanks! It works! It happens to my freshly installed anaconda! Anaconda is truly a headache! I am wondering whether I can use the one installed by brew instead.

Comment: Yes you can. Conda is just Python with a ton of helpful libraries. You can always brew install python, then create a venv, and install only the libs you need in that venv

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you should re-install `curl` via: `brew reinstall curl` so incompatible libraries are re-linked ([`.dylib` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)).

If won't help, double check values of `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` variables as misconfigured values can cause such problems (e.g. check your `~/.bashrc`). Ideally unset them, otherwise if it's not set, try setting it as:

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/X11/lib:/usr/lib"
```

Similar issue: [Dylibs and OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10820981/55075).

Answer (score 0):

Either you have two problems or one nasty one, to find out which type the command `sudo sh -c 'type curl';type curl` if both type commands show the same file you have the tough one, but probably you have two simpler ones: curl is installed twice and your dynamic linker is misconfigured.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem as flyonsnow expressed, and the output of the command you suggested outputs: `curl is /usr/local/bin/curl
curl is /usr/local/bin/curl`, which is the "nasty" problem. Would you have any suggestions on how to solve this one?

Comment: @jared I am getting the same result from both commands as well. In my case, `curl is /usr/bin/curl` for each. Were you able to resolve this? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like anaconda is installing its curl and breaking system's curl.

Type `which curl` and check where it is referencing to. If it is anaconda bins then you need to change `PATH` order.

I use zsh, and fixed it by changing

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

to

`export PATH=$PATH:~/anaconda3/bin`

Answer (score 0):

I recently moved from python 3.6 to 3.7.  I am fairly certain that curl worked before then.  The fact that `conda install libssh2` fixes the problem makes me think that the python upgrade is what broke curl. This may be the explanation that [Sam H](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493116/345580) is missing, i.e., "... makes no sense to me ...".

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this issue after upgrading from openssl from 1.0 to 1.1, you need to upgrade openssh as well:

```
brew upgrade openssh
```

according to [this post](https://blog.junjizhi.com/all/2019/12/17/git-fetch-libssl-error.html).