# Using curl results in error: "Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib ..."

Tags: osx, libraries, curl, homebrew

I had a few issues with the cURL library interfering with Homebrew. After hopefully removing the library (I no longer use it anyway), I started receiving errors whenever I used commands such as `curl` and `brew update`. I fixed `brew` with `brew uninstall git && brew install git`, but I'm still getting the following error with `curl`:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/curl
  Reason: Incompatible library version: curl requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

I'm assuming that I accidentally deleted the wrong library somewhere along the line. Could someone set me along on the right path in fixing the screwup?

Comment: The Error is telling you what you need to do: Curl Requires version 8 of the library and you have 7 so you must install 8

Comment: @eyoung100 Going to the [cURL download page](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) lists 7.43 as the latest version, and Homebrew as the source for the OS X package. Running `brew install curl` results in `Warning: curl-7.43.0 already installed`. I cannot find a source for just a libcurl.4.dylib anywhere.

Comment: Try `brew update && brew upgrade` and lastly `brew reinstall curl`

Comment: Right. Everything's up-to-date, and I've already tried reinstalling. I've also tried uninstalling and seeing if just the OS X-provided curl would work on its own, but I still have the same behavior.

Comment: There is a copy of the library at `/usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib` and `/usr/local/Cellar/curl/7.43.0/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`. Should I create a symlink to one of these copies at `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`? If so, which one?

Comment: No `rm /usr/local/Cellar/curl/*`  OSX has a native copy.  The library is misconfigured.  See: [trying to install curl with homebrew, getting “incompatible library version” for libcurl.4.dylib](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164637/trying-to-install-curl-with-homebrew-getting-incompatible-library-version-for)

Comment: As stated above, removing Homebrew's curl has been attempted. Your linked question suggested either installing from source (which is unwanted) or force uninstalling with `rm` and reinstalling with Homebrew (already attempted and failed). [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214295/dyld-library-not-loaded-usr-local-lib-libcurl-4-dylib-while-executing-curl) would be more relevant, but is still unanswered. As suggested by it, using `sudo sh -c 'type curl';type curl` results in the same file `/usr/local/bin/curl` appearing twice; the "tough" problem.

Comment: Try here... [Curl Command](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105730/curl-command-cant-be-found-osx-utilities-have-been-replaced-by-gnu-coreutils)