# Different package versions in different repositories

Tags: centos, fedora, yum

Following the advise on [Using Awesome window manager on CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/152258/10526), I installed the fedora 19 repository so I could get [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) working on CentOS7.  However, when I run `yum update`, I am getting this error:

```
Error: Package: brlapi-0.6.0-5.fc19.i686 (fedora)
           Requires: brltty = 4.5-5.fc19
           Installed: brltty-4.5-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
               brltty = 4.5-8.el7
           Available: brltty-4.5-5.fc19.x86_64 (fedora)
               brltty = 4.5-5.fc19
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Some more information:

```
; sudo yum list installed | grep  brl     
127:brlapi.x86_64                          0.6.0-8.el7                     @anaconda
128:brltty.x86_64                          4.5-8.el7                       @anaconda
1254:python-brlapi.x86_64                  0.6.0-8.el7                    @anaconda
```

Clearly, the two repositories are in conflict: *How to solve this problem?*

As requested:

```
; sudo yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * epel: mirror-fr2.bbln.org
 * extras: mirror.ukhost4u.com
 * updates: mirror.ukhost4u.com
repo id                       repo name                          status
base/7/x86_64                 CentOS-7 - Base                    enabled:  8,465
base-debuginfo/x86_64         CentOS-7 - Debuginfo               disabled
base-source/7                 CentOS-7 - Base Sources            disabled
centosplus/7/x86_64           CentOS-7 - Plus                    disabled
centosplus-source/7           CentOS-7 - Plus Sources            disabled
epel/x86_64                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu enabled:  6,418
epel-debuginfo/x86_64         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
epel-source/x86_64            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
epel-testing/x86_64           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo/x86_64 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
epel-testing-source/x86_64    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
extras/7/x86_64               CentOS-7 - Extras                  enabled:     77
extras-source/7               CentOS-7 - Extras Sources          disabled
fasttrack/7/x86_64            CentOS-7 - fasttrack               disabled
fedora/x86_64                 Fedora 19 - x86_64                  enabled: 36,253
updates/7/x86_64              CentOS-7 - Updates                 enabled:  1,186
updates-source/7              CentOS-7 - Updates Sources         disabled
repolist: 52,399
```

Here is the `/etc/yum.repos.d/Fedora.repo` file:

```
[fedora]
name=Fedora 19 - $basearch
failovermethod=priority
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/19/Everything/$basearch/os/
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-19
```

Comment: Please add the output of `yum repolist all` to your question.

Comment: @garethTheRed: Questioned edited to add that information.

Comment: You've added the repo for Fedora 7 instead of Fedora 19.  Add the edit you did to the `.repo` file while following the About Something... blog post.

Comment: @garethTheRed: Ah, that's a mistake in how the version number is generated. It should read 19.

Comment: Use `yum-plugin-priorities` to avoid such issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YUM** tries to install:

```
brlapi-0.6.0-5.fc19.i686 (fedora)
```

from @Fedorra repo:

```
Available: brltty-4.5-5.fc19.x86_64 (fedora)
```

Althought there is already installed one:

```
Installed: brltty-4.5-8.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda)
```

from @anaconda repo.

You can try update with disabled repo @fedora:

```
yum update --disablerepo="fedora"
```

Or install package `yum-plugin-priorities` (in fact - you MUST use it, and I'm surprised - why it is still not in default YUM installation):

```
yum install yum-plugin-priorities
```

And then set `ptiorities` in each repo config:

```
# grep -r "priority=" /etc/yum.repos.d/
/etc/yum.repos.d/gf.repo:priority=20
/etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo:priority=1
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:priority=20
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo:priority=20
/etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo:priority=20
```

For example:

```
# head /etc/yum.repos.d/gf.repo
[gf]
name=Ghettoforge packages that won't overwrite core distro packages.
baseurl=http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/gf/el/6/gf/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-gf.el6
failovermethod=priority
priority=20
```

Find more on [CentOS wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities).

Comment: Thank you very much for converting your comment into a great answer.