# Install SVN 1.8 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, subversion

I've tried installing the newest version of SVN but nothing is working.

On yum there is 1.7.
When downloading rpm/zip error occurs when trying to configure.
Setting some additional repositories failed also.

Does anybody have a proven way on how to do it?

Comment: See this [question and answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152258/using-awesome-window-manager-on-centos-7) for reasons you should not compile source packages on binary systems.  As such, [does this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/621983/how-to-install-svn-client-version-1-8-on-centos-rhel-6) help?  BTW, yum is not the package manager.

Comment: Not really, installation of rpms fails.

Comment: Post the output of the failure.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Step 0 : Remove old version of subversion (if already installed)**

```
#yum remove subversion
```

**Step 1: Setup Yum Repository**

Create a new repo file /etc/yum.repos.d/wandisco-svn.repo and add following content

```
[WandiscoSVN]
name=Wandisco SVN Repo
baseurl=http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

**Step 2: Install Subversion Package**

```
# yum clean all
# yum install subversion
```

**Step 3: Verify Subversion Version**

```
# svn --version


svn, version 1.8.13 (r1667537)
   compiled Apr  2 2015, 15:54:41 on i686-pc-linux-gnu

Copyright (C) 2014 The Apache Software Foundation.
This software consists of contributions made by many people;
see the NOTICE file for more information.
Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.or
```

Comment: Under CentOS 7, I also had to do a `yum remove subversion-libs` in order for the install to succeed.

Comment: Not a big deal, but the link is broken. Currently your only options are svn-1.10 and svn-1.11 where you have svn-1.8

Answer (score 1):

For those automating this upgrade in **puppet**:

```ruby
case $::osfamily {
  'RedHat': {
    case $::operatingsystemmajrelease {
      # normally centos 7 has svn 1.7
      '7': {
        yumrepo { "Wandisco SVN Repo":
          name     => 'wandisco-svn',
          baseurl  => 'http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/7/svn-1.8/RPMS/$basearch/',
          gpgcheck => 0,
          enabled  => 1,
        } ->
        exec { 'Remove subversion-libs from 1.7':
          path    => ['bin', '/usr/bin'],
          command => 'rpm -e --nodeps subversion-libs subversion',
          onlyif  => 'rpm -q subversion-libs',
        } ->
        package { 'subversion':
          ensure => '1.8.19-1',
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```