# Gentoo Portage. What exactly 'revdep-rebuild' command does?

Tags: gentoo

I know it's necessary to run `revdep-rebuild` after upgrades of my Gentoo Linux. 
I also kind-of understand that `revdep-rebuild` detects shared libraries conflicts and fixes them somehow. But I want to understand more.

If (hypothetically) I decide to do `revdep-rebuild`'s job manually, how would I do it? How would I select all the binaries to test? How would I check if some particular binary is ok? If there is some problem with a binary - how would I know what package to re-emerge in order to fix it?

Comment: Looking at the source code of `revdep-rebuild` is presumably an option.

Comment: Looking at the source code is the last resort!

Answer (score 3):

1. First, you may find all executables.
2. Then use `ldd` to find `*.so` dependencies.
3. After that, if some shared object doesn't exist, use `qfile` to detect `ebuild` containing it.
4. Finally, re-emerge all packages detected to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the Reasoning Section in [Using Awesome window manager on CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152258/using-awesome-window-manager-on-centos-7/152809#152809).  Whether or not the distribution is binary or not is irrelevant.  This is because the same behavior can occur in all distributions.

Items 4 - 6 in the linked post are what `revdep-rebuld` fixes.  The fancy name for Item 4 is a Reverse Dependency.  The only definition I could find was in this [Wikipedia entry for Dependency Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell). See Conflicting and Circular Dependencies.

`revdep-rebuld`, short for reverse dependency rebuild works by scanning your `/lib` directories for `.so` objects, then compares the version of the **S**hared **O**bject to the version of the Static Library - the `.a` files, if the `static-libs`USE Flag was used.  Both of these are then compared to the output of `ldd`  If there is a mismatch, the package is marked for rebuild, and then rebuilt.

---

All of that is in webKnjaz's answer, except `revdep-rebuild` always starts at his step 2, i.e. it always assumes all packages are broken, therefore it assumes all libraries are broken until scanned.

You should also know that `revdep-rebuild` has been integrated into newer versions of `sys-apps/portage` in the `@preserved-rebuild` set.