# Installing libssl1.0.0 and OpenSSL 1.0 in Debian 6

Tags: linux, debian, compiling, openssl, backports

We are trying to connect to our server where its configuration requires the TLS1.1 protocol for connection. Debian 6 repos do not have direct backports for `libssl1.0.0` and OpenSSL.

We need some guidance in updating `libssl` and compiling a newer OpenSSL version from source. I hope compiling and updating these libraries from source is possible.

Comment: Please DO NOT COMPILE SOURCE on a binary distribution.  The closest you'll be able to get is [0.9.80 - libssl-dev](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libssl-dev) and [0.9.80-4 - openssl](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/openssl).  Also See [Using Awesome window manager on CentOS 7](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152258/using-awesome-window-manager-on-centos-7) for the major reason not to compile.  It might be time to upgrade Debian...

Answer (score 1):

As there isn't a provided backport of OpenSSL 1.x for Debian 6.0, if you're unable to upgrade to a newer Debian release the best option is to create your own backport. As has been suggested, installing from source is **not** recommended.

If you start with the [source package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/openssl) for Debian 8.0 (jessie) it should be reasonably straightforward. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130894/how-to-build-a-debian-ubuntu-package-from-source) on Stack Overflow has a nice summary of what's required to build from source and there's [a guide](https://wiki.debian.org/SimpleBackportCreation) to creating your own backport.

This should be fairly safe as your own OpenSSL package will have a new major number - just make sure you follow the suggestions in that aforementioned Debian guide or **you will** have problems when you upgrade.