# Python3.4 package for Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, python, packet

I'm looking for a way to get python3.4 for debian wheezy. I've been looking on repos but all I could find is 3.2 version. Does anybody know where I can find 3.4 package?

(Or maybe does anybody know if taiga.io-back can  run on 3.2?)

Answer (score 3):

In this  method  we will download the python 3.4 source code compile it and install it

```
    $ sudo  apt-get update 
    $ sudo cd /tmp
    $ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
    $ sudo  cd opt
    $ sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.3/Python-3.4.3.tgz
    $ sudo  tar -xvzf Python-3.4.3.tgz

    $ cd Python-3.4.3
    $ sudo  ./configure
    $ sudo make
    $ sudo make install
```

Comment: This isn't really a helpful solution as it will basically leave the system in a state it is unreliable and re-installing the only safe solution is.

Comment: @hspaans - On the other hand, **it actually answers the question**.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only safe way is to upgrade to Jessie. Seen the issues Python upgrades have I don't expect any backports or LTS updates also as the plan was to only support one release of Python per release.

Also the requirement for Taiga is Ubuntu 14.04 which translates to Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [DeadSnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes).  It's made for Ubuntu, but may help, and I also agree with hspaans, and here is the reason why:

[Using Awesome window manager on CentOS 7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152258/using-awesome-window-manager-on-centos-7)

Comment: Unfortunately this repository is unsupported now.